# show deviation using a line between two points using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

There are say 4 points ( xy coordinates ) in my dataset

```
coordinates =     [[1,2], [10,11], [3,4], [14,15]]
```

Now, plotting them is easy using matplotlib.
But I would like to show them as a deviation between the first and the second point.
It should look like this

```
1,2 --- 10,11
3,4 --- 14,15
```

The --- is a dotted line.

```
fig2 = plt.figure()
shapeplot1 = fig2.add_subplot(111)

coordinates = [[1,2], [10,11], [3,4], [14,15]]

data = np.array(coordinates)
x1, y1 = data.T
shapeplot1.scatter(x1,y1, color='red')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found an answer. One can specifically give two points to the plot function.

```
fig2 = plt.figure()
shapeplot1 = fig2.add_subplot(111)

coordinates = [[1,2], [10,11], [12,12], [14,15]]

data = np.array(coordinates)
x1, y1 = data.T
shapeplot1.scatter(x1,y1, color='red')

shapeplot1.plot([coordinates[0][0], coordinates[1][0]], [coordinates[0][1], coordinates[1][1]])
shapeplot1.plot([coordinates[2][0], coordinates[3][0]], [coordinates[2][1], coordinates[3][1]])

plt.show()
```